# Search Bar Not Returning Anything in my Database

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have been following a series. However, the searchbar we are creating is suppose to return users but it is not. Provided down below is the logic from the video. Any guidance would do

userblock.blade.php

```
<div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left" href="#">
    <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}" src="">
  </a>

  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}</a></h4>
    @if ($user->location)
      <p>{{ $user->location }}</p>
      @endif
  </div>
</div>
```

results.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <h3> Your search for "{{ Request::input('query') }}"</h3>

    @if (!$users->count())
      <p>No results found, sorry.</p>
    @else

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          @foreach ($users as $user)
              @include('user/partials/userblock')
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
      @endif
    @stop
```

SearchController.php

```
<?php

namespace Kermode\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use Kermode\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
  public function getResults(Request $request)
  {
    $query = $request->input('query');

    if (!$query) {
      return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    $users = User::where(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name)"),
    'LIKE', "%($query)%")
    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE' , "%($query)%")
    ->get();

    return view('search.results', compact('users'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using parentheses with LIKE?

Comment: Nearly identical code in this question: [Call to a member function count() on string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50959036)